# Auth0 API Create User returns Client ID Not Found

Tags: api, auth0

I am using the Auth0 Management API page to test creating a user.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_users

I am sending the following body to POST:/api/v2/users:

```
{
  "email":"me@test.com",
  "password":"123DEDed1!",
  "connection":"My-Users"
}
```

However I get the following response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Sandbox Error: Client: '{{REDACTED}}: Client id not found'"
}
```

Obviously the client ID does exist. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: for the POST request, you're passing the token? how you're getting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue was actually internal to another script we had configured in the Action Login Flow